# WakeLock not working

Tags: android, wakelock

I have a wake lock set up so that I can still hear the sound when the screen times out or I press the screen lock button. From what I can understand through reading online is that I only need a partial wake lock. Here is the code but it is not working. No logcat errors

```
package com.androidsleepmachine.gamble;

import android.app.Activity;   
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Spinner;

public class Ship extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {
public static final Integer[] TIME_IN_MINUTES = { 30, 45, 60, 180, 360 };
public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
public Handler handler = new Handler();
public Button button2;
public Spinner spinner2;
private PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
// Initialize the activity
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { 
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "sleeplock");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.ship);
    button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,  
android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TIME_IN_MINUTES);

adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);          
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter); 
}

// Play the sound and start the timer
private void playSound(int resourceId) {
    // Cleanup any previous sound files
    cleanup();
    // Create a new media player instance and start it
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, resourceId);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    // Create the timer to stop the sound after x number of milliseconds
    int selectedTime = TIME_IN_MINUTES[spinner2.getSelectedItemPosition()];
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, selectedTime * 60 * 1000);
}

// Handle button callback
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn2:
            wl.acquire();
            playSound(R.raw.ocean_ship);
            break;
    }
}
 protected void onStop()
  {

      cleanup();
      super.onStop();
  }
// Stop the sound and cleanup the media player
public void cleanup() {
    if (mediaPlayer != null) {
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = null;
         wl.release();
    }
    // Cancel any previously running tasks
    handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
}

// Runnable task used by the handler to stop the sound
public Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        cleanup();
    }
};
}
```

Comment: Did you set permission in manifest for wake lock?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a wake lock](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19070449/using-a-wake-lock)

Answer (score 2):

I would be surprised if Di Vero Labs's answer resolved this since Android documentation says those additional flags do nothing with a partial wakelock.

A wakelock is as simple as you are using it, and it should work:

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "sleeplock");
wl.acquire();
//release
wl.release();
```

Note that you will need to check for nulls, and check that it is not already acquired, etc before doing these methods or you may get a null pointer exception.

I think your issue is that you are calling cleanup() which includes the wakelock release so you aren't really holding a wakelock.  To make sure this works (though might cause battery drain issues) hold your wakelock upfront, then release when you are done, not before you are done else you'll obviously NOT have a wakelock.

I was having a ton of issues because wakelocks weren't working but believe I nailed down the issue to a custom ROM.  So beware! (DONT support custom ROMs, including your own!)

Comment: Can you provide more details regarding problems with a custom ROM and partial wakelocks?  I'm seeing something where an app that acuqires a partial wakelock works on another phone but  doesn't work on a phone with Cyanogenmod. This is a tough topic to google for as you get all sorts of results regarding how to kill wakelocks.

Comment: I should clarify - I totally support (and use!!) custom ROMs.  But the fact remains that they haven't gone through thorough testing like if it came from a top manufacturer.  So that's what I mean by don't support custom roms, from an app perspective.  I have a popular app where a lot of issues I narrowed down to only existing on custom roms.  Eg a specific reproduceable issue exists on a Nexus 5 CM modified rom, but not on same android version stock untouched.  I can't explain why.  I've reached out to Devs of custom roms but never got anywhere.

Comment: I also found core android functions from API dont work on custom roms, obviously specific to that rom, but again, cant explain why.

Comment: I'm not sure why my answer is getting downvoted (no reasons or arguments left), but can assure you I've spent a LOT of time troubleshooting and researching wakelocks and my answer is accurate.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK |
                PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP |
                PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "sleeplock");
```

I've found the "PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP" alleviates a few of the same issues I was having.

Also make sure:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

is declared in your manifest.

Comment: I do have the permission in the manafest. Also I tried your code and it still stops playing the sound when the screen lock button is pressed or it times out